# How do I lock down the gems for my rails project?

Tags: heroku, bundler

This might be an obvious question but I'm having trouble googling for a best practice. I'm using Rails 3.0 and Bundler.

I started developing a Rails app on my work laptop. I added gem names to my gem file and ran bundle install. When I did this I didn't pay much attention to what version of the gems I needed, I just let Bundler install the latest versions. Everything was working fine.

I pushed this app up to Heroku and it just worked.

1. Is Heroku using the gem versions defined in my Gemfile.lock file? Or is it fetching the latest versions using the Gemfile and installing those?

   Then I got a new laptop. So I decide to clone the git repo on that laptop as well. I installed RVM, cloned the repo from GitHub and then ran bundle install locally. The problem was that because I didn't specify the gem versions in the Gemfile, running `bundle install` downloaded the latest gem versions. I made some CSS changes and pushed up to Heroku, and was surprized to find the app broken. Apparently the paperclip gem now requires some other aws gem or something or other.

   So I looked through the git logs on Gemfile.lock, found the previous working version of paperclip and put that version number in the Gemfile. Repushed to heroku and it's working again.
2. How do I avoid this problem from happening? Should I always be putting the gem version number in my Gemfile? Should I be vendoring my gems (which I've not done before, how to do it)?

Comment: Are you *sure* it installed the latest versions? Did you not have the Gemfile.lock file checked into your repository?

Comment: yes I did have Gemfile.lock checked into my repo.  But when I ran bundle install on my new laptop it fetched the latest gem versions and overwrote the local Gemfile.lock.

Comment: If that is what actually happened then you've encountered a bug in Bundler. Ensure you're using the latest version of Bundler and if you can definitively reproduce this behavior, [report it](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/new).

Comment: hmm... so what you're saying is, once the Gemfile.lock is present, than running bundle install will use the gems in the lock file.  Including when heroku deploys.  So I guess I must have run bundle update at some point...

Comment: Yup, that's what the lock file is for. The version constraints specified in the Gemfile are used when running `bundle update`, but otherwise the lock file is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question one, depends on how gems are declared into Gemfile: for example declaring `gem "omniauth"`,  will bundle last omniauth gem into heroku Gemfile.lock at deploy/compile time, while if you specify `gem "omniauth", "0.3.4"` you'll get exactly "0.3.4" on Heroku.

Vendoring is deprecated in rails >= 3.2.2

and yes,  is better to specify all your gem versions into Gemfile and when you need to update, doit one at a time by running locally `bundle update omniauth` after putting the new version in Gemfile ...

Comment: why is vendoring deprecated?  What happens if the old gem version is no longer available at large?

Comment: That's not true. The only command that will modify the Gemfile.lock (assuming it already exists) is `bundle update`.

Comment: @sketchfemme Vendoring is deprecated because it's a poor way to manage things. Gems that were available on Rubygems will continue to be available as long as rubygems.org is up and running, so I don't really see the concern there. Vendoring will be gone in Rails 4.0.

Comment: After making a change to a specific gem in your Gemfile, the next bundle install will try to update the gems in your snapshot too (Gemfile.lock), without forcing an update to any of the other gems in your Gemfile. If you don't specify the version in Gemfile is easy end up with different Gemfile.lock after running bundle time later on different platforms (laptop or cloud providers ...)